# Content Security Policy violation in a fresh Ember app

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, content-security-policy

Today I created my first Ember App using the ember-cli:

```
ember new my-app
cd my-app
ember serve
```

so that it appears by url *localhost:4200*.
I fail on the next step:

- Change content of the basic template *application.hbs*

After I perform some text changes I hit Cmd+S and reload the page the content remains the same.
The browser console is "clean", but I get error messages in the terminal

> Content Security Policy violation: {}

The content of **application.hbs**:

```
<h2 id="title">This is a test message</h2>
{{outlet}}
```

My environment:
ember version: 0.2.3, node: 0.12.2, npm: 2.7.6.

I've searched for answers on Stack, but mostly they concern apps that have some external data requests, but my project is brand new and fresh, so I'm confused.

Looking forward to your replies,
Thanks!

UPDATE:

Some additional info:

I figured out that the problem is that the ember app does not "hear" the trigger, when a file has been changed. I don't receive a

```
file changed templates/application.hbs
```

notification in the terminal. Something **globally** is blocking or interrupting the regular app run.

Still looking forward receiving your suggestions !

Comment: In addition:
The content **DOES** change if I stop and start the server again, but that's not the "correct" workflow I guess

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually reload, livereload is setup for all ember-cli apps

Comment: Also what are you changing the content to? Could you please add your `application.hbs` code. And make sure you npm & bower install.

Comment: After many tries to make nice with content-security-policy, I've removed it from my package.json, as it's just too much of a pain for me to get set up across environments.  Maybe one day I'll work through it, but your app will run just fine without it.

Comment: @Kitler, sure (added to question body). 

Everything installed and updated: 
npm -v = 2.7.5
bower -v = 1.4.1

Comment: @mpowered, I deleted the line "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0" from package.json. Unfortunately didn't change the situation.

Comment: Did you restart ember server?

Comment: Removing the check that's warning you of vulnerabilities doesn't count as fixing your vulnerabilities....

Comment: @Kitler, agree. I created a topic on the official Ember.js website. Hopefully someone would help, because the situation is ugly

Comment: What were the specifics of the CSP error? mine looked like this: Content Security Policy violation: {"csp-report":..."source-file":"chrome-extension://iblijlcdoidgdpfknkckljiocdbnlagk"}}. Obviously, mine were due to a Chrome extension trying to access the pages (Goo.gl URL Shortener, for one). I disabled the offending extensions using the IDs in the report, and my CSP errors vanished.

Comment: @JKubecki no specific text. Only empty curly brackets:
Content Security Policy violation: {}

I would create another topic with further investigations today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem has nothing to do with Content Security Policy violation. It is a local issue of the file system. The terminal didn't display messages that changes were triggered in the template file **application.hbs** - as a result no updates.

The current solution is starting the ember server with an option:

```
ember serve --watcher=polling
```

As soon as I figure out the initial problem I'll return and update this answer.
Cheers